# Simple algebra question

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$\dfrac{\qquad\dfrac{5p+10}{p^2-4}\qquad}{\dfrac{3p-6}{(p-2)^2}}$$

Im all confused about this question. Can someone go through it step by step. Can you please list when I can cancel numbers. Thanks.

Comment: you are correct in that you can only cancel whole factors of the numerator and denominator, not parts of a sum or difference

Comment: The big trick is to realize that $5p+10 = 5(p+2)$, $p^2-4 = (p-2)(p+2)$, and $3p-6 = 3(p-2)$.  Thus, you can cancel out a factor of $p+2$ from the top two terms, and $p-2$ from the bottom two terms, and you get: $$\dfrac{\qquad\dfrac{5}{p-2}\qquad}{\dfrac{3}{p-2}}$$ which obviously can be simplified some more...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Remember that
$$\frac{\quad\frac{a}{b}\quad}{\frac{c}{d}} = \frac{a}{b}\div \frac{c}{d} = \frac{ad}{bc}.$$
If you think of the fraction as a "sandwich", with $a$ and $d$ the bread, $b$ and $c$ the ham-and-cheese, then the bread goes on top and the ham and cheese go on the bottom.

Alternatively, dividing by $x$ is the same as multiplying by $\frac{1}{x}$, and 
$$\frac{1}{\quad\frac{c}{d}\quad} = \frac{d}{c}$$
so
$$\frac{\quad\frac{a}{b}\quad}{\frac{c}{d}} = \frac{a}{b}\times\frac{1}{\quad\frac{c}{d}\quad} = \frac{a}{b}\times \frac{d}{c} = \frac{ad}{bc}.$$

Comment: Thanks guys. Im still a bit confused with cancelling. Say I can only cancel if there are only multiplications attached to each other? So I couldent cancel the a in : a + b/ a + c ?

Comment: @John: If you mean $(a+b)/(a+c)$, you are indeed correct: the $a$s **do not** cancel. Just do a simple example: take $(2+1)/(2+2)$. I that the same thing as $1/2$? No.

Answer (score 7):

$$\frac{{5p + 10}}{{p^2  - 4}}\bigg/\frac{{3p - 6}}{{(p - 2)^2 }} = \frac{{5p + 10}}{{p^2  - 4}}\frac{{(p - 2)^2 }}{{3p - 6}} = \frac{{5(p + 2)}}{{(p + 2)(p - 2)}}\frac{{(p - 2)(p - 2)}}{{3(p - 2)}} = \frac{5}{3}$$

Comment: Note that this is defined if $p \notin \{-2,2\}$.

Comment: Thanks guys. Im still a bit confused with cancelling. Say I can only cancel if there are only multiplications attached to each other? So I couldent cancel the a in : a + b/ a + c ?

Comment: @John, indeed, you cannot cancel the $a$ in $(a+b)/(a+c)$.

Comment: And, on the other hand, $(ab)/(ac)=b/c$.

Comment: You can "cancel" (by division) *factors*, not *terms*

Comment: To cancel additive terms: $(a+b) - (a+c) = b-c$